# MySQL: Table crash after Alter Table

Tags: mysql, sql, crash, runtime-error, alter

I just tried to add an index to one of my tables and the operation failed and crashed my MySQL Workbench. Later, running queries against that table failed.

Structure of the table:

```
PK(CHAR(8), CHAR(4), CHAR(40)), CHAR(8)
```

I tried to index the second column.

I don't even know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the kine of index that you want to create (primary key, unique, index).

For primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE PK ADD PRIMARY KEY (column2_name);
```

For unique:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON PK(column2_name);
```

For index :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON PK(column2_name);
```